# How to hide unwanted columns from getting displayed in a Datagrid view from Sharepoint 2010 using C sharp?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am getting all the fields(columns)  from a document library in Sharepoint 2010 wherein only 5 columns are visible in sharepoint 2010 UI but while getting it programmatically i am getting 24 columns in a datagridview even after puttin a check that if fields are hidden then do not display them. Is there any way to get those only fields which i am able to view from sharepoint UI using C Sharp??

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting the columns in the SPQueryObject, there is a property called ViewFields in SQPquery, you can define what columns you would want to display. Something like this :

```
objQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Title' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get the columns from the default view of the list. You can get the columns from the other views too depending upon the columns you require.

NLV